# How to detect DoS attacks / manually block IP on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, administrator, denial-of-service

I have a VPS with Ubuntu. I host a small website (~10 visitors at the same time). Sometimes the website starts lagging. It lags so bad that my SSH connection starts lagging too. Running `top` says that 2 instances of `apache2` take up 50% CPU each.

I assume this is a `DoS` attack. I've copy-paste installed a few `iptables` scripts that made sense, but this has not helped.

I installed `libapache2-mod-evasive` -- I'm sure it blocks the attacker, but I'm still lagging.

What can I do? Can I at least find the IP of the attacker?

I have strong experience with Linux, but almost zero experience with being a server admin.

Comment: Are you serving static files or dynamic content. The lag *could* be due to inefficient database queries when creating dynamic content.

Comment: @Stacey, content is PHP+MySQL. I agree that it *could* be from that, but I know for a fact that it's not. Not only do I log slow queries, but my database server is on another VPS. More importantly CPU is used  up by `apache2`, not `mysqld`

Comment: Do the queries return large amounts of data that take a long time for PHP to process? Do you log script execution time in addition to query times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Apache access log for repeated attempts by a similar IP address, `/var/log/httpd/access_log` is the usual location.

You may also be interested in an automated solution such as [DDoS Deflate](http://deflate.medialayer.com/) or [PSAD](http://cipherdyne.org/psad/). I'd also strongly recommend [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) for Apache itself.

Comment: I definitely use `modsec`. Are there user-friendly viewers / statistic  analyzers for access_log ?

Comment: @Mikhail there are many, AWStats being one of the bigger ones: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you hardened Apache or your OS?

Are you able to post any logs?

This may help a bit.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html

Answer (score -1):

I can't suggest enough Fail2ban. It is a daemon that runs in the background and monitors all of your log files for suspicious activity and blocks the suspicious activity based on the log file errors. This means you must create the error log files in the first place, for web servers you can usually do this. I've done it for NGINX just recently, but I'm sure there's a similar directive for Apache.